# capture-recapture - Chance of tagging twice

Tags: probability

A friend of mine asked me if I could solve this following problem, and it has turned out to be rather difficult (or I just cant find the answer)

Let N be the total population. We take a samle of K individuels and mark them. Then we take another sample of n individuels and mark them. the question goes: What is the probability that exactly k of the n individuels in the latest samle were already marked?

obviously the answer depends on the binomial coefficient, but I can't really get anywhere with a solution. Any help?

Comment: After first round, there are $K$ people marked and $N - K$ unmarked in the population. Now for the second sample, what's the probability that $k$ people will be from $K$ and $n-k$ from $N-K$?

Hint: Hypergeomertic Distribution

Answer (score 0):

Presumably all choices of $n$ individuals are equiprobable. The total number of ways to choose $n$ individuals is $\binom Nn$. The number of favourable ways is $\binom Kk\binom{N-K}{n-k}$, since we can choose $k$ individuals from $K$ and $n-k$ from $N-K$. Thus the desired probability is

$$
\frac{\binom Kk\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom Nn}=\frac{\binom nk\binom{N-n}{K-k}}{\binom NK}\;.
$$

The second form can be obtained either algebraically from the first form, or by noting the symmetry between the two samples and asking for the probability that the first sample contains exactly $k$ individuals marked in the second sample.